# obsolete enum member who is stored in Database

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, enums

I have an enum in an entity of the EF6 and it is stored as a byte in the database when saving the enum.

Now I want to mark a value of the Enum as Obsolete, but there will still be data using this value. It just is not used in the code.

Technically, I would like to delete this value in the code, but what would you do with the old data?

Migrate?

Comment: I would mark it as obsolete, and add some logic to your application that forces the user to change the value to a non-obsolete value. Except for when you _know_ what the new value has to be of course, than you can just migrate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think Migration is the only way to solve our problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good practice is to follow these steps:

- data migration: replace the obsolete value into your database with the correct one.
- cleaning the code: remove the enum value because it is no longer neeeded.

If data migration can't be done because old value is still kept into the database, so I will follow these steps:

- each property setter or method that set a field from your enum must add some defensive code. When setting with the obsolete enum value you throw an exception `InvalidOperationException` with a explicit message.
- in the enum definition, I will put a XML comments with a `<remark>` that will help developers to know about what's going on.
- optional step: going further by adding custom [code analyzer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/dn879356.aspx) to track the use of that value.

Notice I don't decorate the enum value with `[Obsolete]` attribute because this attribute means two things:

- the code is obsolete at version X.
- the code will be removed in a version after X: version Y.

Those two things let developers that use version X to clean their actual code base (remove all use of the obsolete enum value) and get ready for version Y (no changes will be needed because all the job is done when using version X). You can't use `[Obsolete]` attribute because you said that old data will still exist into the database so you may need to display somewhere and you're not following the two things I said about `[Obsolete]` attribute.

Comment: Thank you, that was my first thought when I read the requirement. i think this attribute is first and foremost a technical support for developers and you should also use it after your description. since only we use the code and there are no other developers, I  want to remove the value directly. Thanks